# Displaying User HTML - Alternatives to using iframe

Tags: html

I have a HTML editor that allows users to edit their page. I am using an iframe to preview the edits.

I am looking for a solution to displaying HTML/CSS without rendering it in an iframe. I know using an iframe prevents HTML/CSS from conflicting with the parent site. Just wondered if there were other ways of displaying User HTML/CSS content without having to worry about the possible altering of the parent/main website when previewed.

If DIV's are an option, how would I secure the display of it?

Comment: What is wrong with using an iframe?

Comment: Wanted to know if there was a better/lighter way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No. There are other ways, but from your comment it appears you're looking for a lighter way, and everything else is going to be pretty heavy and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: What are some options then? I am open